# How to check if text assigned to TextObject grows to next line in Crystal Report

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

I am using `CrystalReportViewer` in .aspx page for generating a simple Report liek below:

```
 ReportClass rpt = new Report();
    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt;
    
    TextObject txtName = (TextObject)rpt.ReportDefinition.ReportObjects["txtName"];
    txtName.Text = GetNameFromDB();
```

Sometimes the function GetNameFromDB() returns long name and the textObject `txtName` grows to next line.  Is there any way to check if txtName grows to next line or not? How can i check this?

Comment: doesn't the textobject have a wrap property, i think it called "Can Grow", you just need to specify the number of lines

Comment: I'm not aware of a way to check if a field has grown due to text wrapping when the "Can Grow" property is enabled, but I can't say for certain there isn't a way to do this.  You may want to reach out to SAP with this question to confirm whether its possible or not.  It may also help if you could describe why you need to know when the field grows and describe any issues that you have when it does.  Someone may have some thoughts on how to address your issue in a different way.

Answer (score 0):

For certain use cases, yes, there is a way. But it requires use of extra code or a Crystal Reports UFL (User Function Library).

But, as suggested by R. McMillan, please explain your use case.

For example, simply placing the objects below the text object in their own section (split section option in Crystal) may offer a simple solution.

Comment: The purpose is I don't want an extra empty space between the textObjects placed vertically. I want to check if textObject grows to nex line then I want to place other textObjects (the textObjects placed below the growing textObject "txtName") at new line in the report and if "txtName" do not grows to next line, then other textObjects should not be placed at next line.

Comment: The "other text objects" are placed immediately below the first text object?
If so, simply split the section (e.g. Detail a and Detail b). Place the first text object in the first section and place the other text objects in the section below.